# OutOfMemoryError getting in websphere application server 6.1 with jdk1.5

Tags: java, websphere

```
native_stdout.log:Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 289064 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?
native_stdout.log:Exception in thread "CompilerThread0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 475344 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?
native_stdout.log:Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 5242880 bytes for GrET* in /BUILD_AREA/jdk1.5.0_18/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/growableArray.cpp. Out of swap space?
native_stdout.log:Exception in thread "CompilerThread1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 8744 bytes for unsigned char in /BUILD_AREA/jdk1.5.0_18/hotspot/src/share/vm/code/codeBlob.cpp. Out of swap space?
```

Comment: Standard answer: profile it and fix memoryleaks in your code and/or give it sufficient memory.

Comment: When does this occur?  What is WebSphere doing?  Compiling some servlets or some such?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is ... as the error messages suggest ... your machine is out of swap space, and the operating system is refusing to allocate more (virtual) memory to the JVM.

If this is the case, you could try adding more swap space; see `man swapon` for example.

Another possibility is that your JVM is hitting a process resource limit on the amount of virtual memory it can request; see `man ulimit`.

In either case, simply increasing the JVM's max heap size using the `-Xmx ...` option is NOT going to help.